# How to convert a sequence of letters into a list of numbers? Python Pandas

Tags: python

For example:
If we have a column in a data frame with the sequence: 'ABCD'
How can we transform it into a list: ['A','B','C','D']
This would be done in a pandas dataframe.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just `.map()` the `list()` function to the series that has the string values like `'ABCD'`.

For example:

```
from pandas import DataFrame

df = DataFrame(['ABCD', 'EFGH', 'IJKL'])
df[0] = df[0].map(list)

print(df)
```

Output:

```
              0
0  [A, B, C, D]
1  [E, F, G, H]
2  [I, J, K, L]
```